# channel() Missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Television(object):

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def channel(self, number):
        print("You are currently tuning into" + self.lst[number-1])


def volume(reduce, loudness=0):
    loudness -= reduce
    return loudness


def main():
    channel = ['News','Sport','Movie','Music','Kids']
    TV = Television(channel)
    numbers = int(input("What do u want to watch?"))
    watch = Television.channel(numbers)
    reduce = int(input("Too loud? Reduce volume!"))
    adjust = Television(reduce)

main()

input("Press enter to exit")
```

As seen in the code above, channel method only requires 1 arguments, which is number. However, when I call out `Television.channel(numbers)` , where `numbers` is a value for the user to input, it returns the following error as seen in the title. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please fix the indentation so that we can see **where** everything should go into. This is kind of important in Python code!

Comment: Seriously , fix the indentation or your question is no good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `channel()` method on the instance `TV`:

```
class Television(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def channel(self, number):
        print("You are currently tuning into " + self.lst[number-1])

def main():
    channels = ['News', 'Sport', 'Movie', 'Music', 'Kids']
    TV = Television(channels)
    number = int(input("What do u want to watch? "))
    watch = TV.channel(number)    

main()

input("Press enter to exit ")
```

Running the above code:

```
What do u want to watch? 3
You are currently tuning into Movie
Press enter to exit 
>>>
```